# Inserting Record in another table and Updating row of another table in ADF 11.1.1

Tags: sql

l have a table (Order Details) in ADF 11.1.1 with one of the columns based on LOV (Products Table) . When inserting new row into (Order Details) , l want to update quantity column of the Products table . When l insert a row record in order details l want a code to reduce quantity of product by subtracting number entered in order details table.

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: have trying a database trigger but ist not compiling. Syntax below create or replace
TRIGGER tg_ai_table2
AFTER INSERT ON table2
FOR EACH ROW
begin
  UPDATE Table1
     SET qty = qty - NEW.issued
   WHERE product = new.product;
   end;
error encountered Error(8,20): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "NEW"."PRODUCT": invalid identifier

Comment: Well after trying a number of codes l managed to create a compound trigger that have a virtual table in which data will inserted first and then use that table to update the product table. It is working well. Is there any book with in depth notes on manipulation data in ADF particularly on doDML() method??